# Name for collection of all derivatives (and/or integrals) for a given function?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Is there a name for the set of functions that make up a function's derivatives? Integrals?

For example's sake, let's say there is a fourth degree polynomial function $f(x) = 1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4$. What would the collection $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$, ... be called? Can this be extended to integration?

---

I tried searching for something along the lines of generalizing the set of derivatives or a generalization of gradient, but found generalizations in the multivariate or different coordinate senses, not to n'th derivatives.

Comment: Apologies if the question is overly simplistic, loaded, or incorrectly tagged. I don't know enough math at this time to ask better, but would appreciate edits :)

Comment: I don't think that set of functions has a name. If you have a context in which you will need to refer to it often you can make up your own. If you [edit] the question to show us some of that context perhaps we can suggest something.

Comment: I don't have any particular context. Just studying calculus, and figured there has to be some work on this set/space/whatever this would be called, since there's a clear pattern here for generalization.

Comment: The collection $\{f(x),f^\prime(x),f^{\prime \prime} (x),\cdots\}$ is called "the function $f$ and its derivatives."

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question really depends on your motivation for it. If you just want a name for the sequence of pointwise values of a function and its derivatives at a point, then "the sequence of pointwise values of a function and its derivatives at a point" is an answer.

However, you probably want to do something with this sequence, thus you need a definition that hints at some more structure on it. In that case, the closest notion I can think of is the one of "Jet" ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics). It arises in the study of symmetries of differential equations, because it allows to rewrite such equations as algebraic ones; see [Why is a PDE a submanifold (and not just a subset)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1761598/8157).

(On these things, I like the book of Peter Olver "Applications of Lie groups to differential equations").

Comment: I don't think so. A jet is (essentially) a Taylor polynomial, not the set of derivatives. But perhaps this will help the OP.

Comment: A jet seems to be an approximating form for a particular function. Though it relies on n'th derivatives, it isn't a collection of derivatives itself.

Comment: @EthanBolker: that's a fair point. I am updating my answer to address it.